# how to group ui elements ios

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I'm looking for a way to group some ui elements together just like the twitter app does but I can't find anything which suits my needs.

equivalent to jpanel in java or groupbox in .net

this is what I'm talking about:
http://i46.tinypic.com/169etxi.jpg

Comment: Like putting them all in a UIView?  Have you tried anything?  Do you have any code to add to your question?  Any screen shots to point out which portion of the twitter app you are talking about?

Comment: Looks like a UITableView with custom cells

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One, not so neat, solution is to create an image and use it as the background and put the ui elements on top of it.
Here is the image I used(retina).
http://tinypic.com/r/6i9m3b/6

Answer (score 9):

On interface builder, you can embed ui elements in a view or scrollview. Just select all the elements you want to group and then click Editor -> Embed In -> View/Scrollview

Answer (score 7):

Grouping UI elements in UIKit is as simple as putting child views into a parent `UIView`. Just use the `addSubview:` method.

From the docs:

> Views can embed other views and create sophisticated visual
>   hierarchies. This creates a parent-child relationship between the view
>   being embedded (known as the subview) and the parent view doing the
>   embedding (known as the superview).

Here are the docs:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html